# How can I provide multiple currency support in my EOS smart contract

Tags: deferred-transactions, transfer, coin

Can we transfer other crypto currencies which are based on different blockchains lets say bitcoin, litecoin, neo or ether, using the EOS smart contract. I heard that there is gonna be feature to communicate with different blockchains in EOS. Is it implemented or in future plan?

Comment: you can't do it on-chain unless atomic swaps with those currencies exist (they don't for the time being) other websites astract that they're using multiple blockchains by using one user interface for example